# scrambled alphabet code doesn't work properly

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
  {
    char cleartxt[256];
    printf("what do you want to cipher? (lower cases only)\n");
    fgets(cleartxt, sizeof(cleartxt), stdin);
    int len = strlen(cleartxt);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) //converting uppercases in lowercases
    {
      if (isupper(cleartxt[i]))
      {
        cleartxt[i] = (tolower(cleartxt[i]));
      }
    }
    char scrambled_alphabet[256];
    printf("put here your scrambled alphabet\n");
    fgets(scrambled_alphabet, sizeof(scrambled_alphabet), stdin);
    int alph_len = strlen(scrambled_alphabet);

    char alphabet[27] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

       for (int i = 0; i <= (len - 1); i++)    //algorhmithm for the cipher
       {
           for (int j = 0; j <= (alph_len - 1); j++)
           {  if (cleartxt[i] == alphabet[j])
             {
              cleartxt[i] = scrambled_alphabet[j];
             }
           }
       }
       printf("%s", cleartxt);
    return 0;
  }
```

This code gets an alphabet where you put a word with no repeating letters at the start of the alphabet and then the rest of the alphabet without repeating letters(ex. zebracdfghijklmnopqstuvwxy), then it ciphers a word by swapping the letters of the alphabet to the letters of the scrambled alphabet in the same place (ex. car becomes bzp).

I wrote this code for the cipher but it doesn't work well, the letter "a" becomes a random letter, the same thing happens at the first letter of the clear text depending on the word i use on the scrambled alphabet.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to check with `isupper()` before calling `tolower()` because it only converts uppercase letters.

Comment: Another: code like `i <= (len - 1);` is less readable than `i < len;` and in some cases, can be wrong.

Comment: Also: don't forget there is a newline retained at the end the input strings by `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your inner loop:

```
printf("i=%d %c to j=%d %c\n", i, cleartxt[i], j, scrambled_alphabet[j]);
```

just before assigning `cleartxt[i] = scrambled_alphabet[j];`.

It prints out the following:

```
i=0 c to j=2 b
i=1 a to j=0 z
i=1 z to j=25 y
i=2 r to j=17 p
byp
```

Notice there are two prints for `i=1`. You need to stop the inner loop once you make an assignment.